# Find where the function is not injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\}$. Solve the following equation in the reals
$$\frac{(x^2-x+1)^3}{x^2(x-1)^2}=\frac{(a^2-a+1)^3}{a^2(a-1)^2}$$

My thoughts: I've tried substitution $x(x-1)=u$ and $a(a-1)=v$ but that lead me nowhere. I've also tried $x^2-x+1=\frac{x^3+1}{x+1}$ but that didn't help me either.

I was wondering if there is a nice solution to this problem.

Comment: this is a Problem from a former Matholympiad in the former GDR

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Any idea from which year or are there solutions by chance? This was also given as a question on a Serbian contest but I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: i have posted the 'solution' the rest is easy

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the main idea is to factorize all:
$$ \left( xa-1 \right)  \left( x-1+a \right)  \left( xa-a+1 \right) 
 \left( xa-a-x \right)  \left( -x+a \right)  \left( xa-x+1 \right) 
=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^2+1=2kx$ and $a^2+1=2ma$.

Thus, $\frac{(2k-1)^3}{k-1}=\frac{(2m-1)^3}{m-1},$ which is  easier.

Answer (score 1):

You might substitute $x=t+1/2$ and $a=b+1/2$. Then
$$
x^2-x+1=t^2+t+\frac{1}{4}-t-\frac{1}{2}+1=t^2+\frac{3}{4}
$$
Then the equation becomes
$$
\frac{(t^2+\frac{3}{4})^3}{(t^2-\frac{1}{4})^2}=
\frac{(b^2+\frac{3}{4})^3}{(b^2-\frac{1}{4})^2}
$$
Now set $u=t^2+\frac{3}{4}$ and $c=b^2+\frac{3}{4}$, so you get
$$
\frac{u^3}{(u-1)^2}=\frac{c^3}{(c-1)^2}
$$
and so
$$
(c-1)^2u^3-c^3u^2+2c^3u-c^3=0
$$
This clearly has a factor $u-c$:
$$
(u-c)\bigl((c-1)^2u^2+(c-2c^2)u+c^2\bigr)=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-x=a^2-a$ is clealy solution. Then every solution is shape of $x^2-x=b$ so factorize

$(x^2-x-a^2+a)(x^2-x+c)(x^2-x+d)=x^6+・・・+1$

Also we can find $x=\dfrac1{1-a}$ is solution. So, $x=-\dfrac a{1-a}$ by $\alpha+\beta=1$. Then $d=(1-a)/a^2$. This leads last solution is $x=-\dfrac{1-a}a,\dfrac1a$.